# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on NSClassFromString when class doesn't exist

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access

NSClassFromString is supposed to return a nil when it can't find a class, but I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash on this:

```
classname = "foo"
var fooClass = NSClassFromString(classname)
```

How can I safely check for the non-existence of a class in Swift & Objective-C?

Comment: Is the problem only with Swift or also with Objective-C?

Comment: Both. My project is using a lot of swift & objective-c classes that need to be instantiated on the fly.

Comment: @ScottMcCoy I don't think rmaddy was asking about whether the classes you're instantiating are Objective-C or Swift, but rather if the code in your snippet has problems in both languages.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a problem that can't be reproduced.  Assuming that `classname` is defined as a `var` somewhere, the 2nd line will produce a warning (because `fooClass` will have the type `AnyClass!` which may be unexpected), but it is set to `nil` as user expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is working under Swift:

```
var classname = "foo"
var fooClass = NSClassFromString(classname)
```

And this one too with Objective-C:

```
NSString* classname = @"foo";
id fooClass = NSClassFromString(classname);
```

Your code seems correct

**Did you try to upgrade Xcode in order to have the latest version of Swift?**

Comment: This seems more like a comment (and close reason) than it seems an answer.

Comment: @nhgrif - But the code segments would be mutilated if put into a comment.

Comment: @HotLicks "Copy & pasted code from question and it works.  Translated to Objective-C, also works.  Voting to close as not reproducible."  ??  Also... before my edit, the code snippets were just incased in backticks anyway...

Comment: In the Objective-C code, `fooClass` should be declared as `Class`, not `id`.

Comment: @rmaddy: `Class` is just a specialized `id`

Comment: Upgrading to Xcode 6.3 and Swift 1.2 seems to have fixed the issue. Strange that none of you guys were able to repro it. Ah well, thanks for the help! :D

Comment: @newacct `Class` is a typedef for a pointer to `objc_class`, not `id`. `NSClassFromString` has a return type of `Class`, not `id`. It's better to use the appropriate type.

Comment: @newacct Everything is just a specialized `id`...

Comment: @rmaddy: `Class` can hold any pointer to a class object. `id` can hold any pointer to an object. Class objects are objects. ergo `id` can be used anywhere `Class` is used.

Comment: @nhgrif: not `double`